# Returning data with heavy use of predicates

Tags: c#, moq

I am using .Net Core 2 web API with an architecture that uses predicates heavily which is causing some issues when I try to unit test my code with Moq.

Each of my repositories inherit from a base repository that has basic methods like this:

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}

public virtual IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
}
```

In my User controller Signup method I want to make sure that I don't allow duplicate emails and I do so like this:

```
var emailCheck = _userRepository.GetSingle(x => x.Email == user.Email);
if (emailCheck != null)
{
    // duplicate
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict, "This email is already in use.");
}
```

In my unit test I want to have a test to make sure that we don't allow duplicates so I set this up:

```
public void Signup_Fail_DuplicateEmail_Controller_Test()
{
    var user = UserHelper.CreateSignupUser();
    user.Email = "duplicate@test.com";
    var uRepo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

    uRepo.Setup(u => u.GetSingle(x => x.Email == user.Email)).Returns(user);

    var uc = new UserController(uRepo.Object);
    var result = uc.Signup(user);

    var status = Assert.IsType<StatusCodeResult>(result);
    Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict, status.StatusCode);
}
```

The Setup method always returns null no matter what I do. Now I have read in several places that Moq does not work with FirstOrDefault and other helper methods like it, but I am not sure what to do since my architecture is so reliant on predicates. Certainly want to avoid reworking my base repository, but I need to be able to run tests like this.

Thoughts?

Comment: If that's actual code, you do realize you are losing most performance gains of Entity Framework by using 100% synchronous queries, right? You are adding complexity and losing performance all at once

Comment: I am certainly no master of EF so I am open to suggestions as to better ways to do it.

Comment: Whenever you are working with a query and see two methods, like `First` and `FirstAsync`, you should select the Async version. Of course, that's impossible for your repository with methods like `FindBy` without leaking the EF dependency. But that's what happens when people insist on using repositories...

Comment: There is no way to compare the expressions so the mock will always return null. If this is just to test the flow of the method under test, you can just use `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()` for the argument matcher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to compare the expressions so the mock will always return null.

If this is just to test, in isolation, the flow of the method under test, you can use `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()` for the argument matcher.

```
public void Signup_Fail_DuplicateEmail_Controller_Test() {
    //Arrange
    var user = UserHelper.CreateSignupUser();
    user.Email = "duplicate@test.com";
    var uRepo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

    uRepo
        .Setup(_ => _.GetSingle(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()))
        .Returns(user);

    var uc = new UserController(uRepo.Object);

    //Act
    var result = uc.Signup(user);

    //Assert
    var status = Assert.IsType<StatusCodeResult>(result);
    Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict, status.StatusCode);
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

The above works well for testing expected behavior in isolated unit test.

If however you want to test the actual expression then that can be done using an in-memory integration test or an actual database.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.